# How to use ObjectDataSource with Grid View?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What should I right in the cs file of web form when using object data source for populating grid view?

i am now using

```
GridView1.DataSource = OrdersData.GetOrders(txtSearchInOrders.Text);
GridView1.DataBind();
```

OrdersData is my DAL class in which a method was defined for retrieving data from db:

```
public class OrdersData
    {
public static DataSet GetOrders(string searchString)
        {
            string sqlQuery = null;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                sqlQuery = String.Format("GetOrders");
            else
                sqlQuery = String.Format("SearchInOrders");

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, connection);


                sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                {
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@SearchString", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters["@SearchString"].Value = searchString;
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters["@SearchString"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                }

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds);

                return ds;
            }
        }
}
```

so when i associate my grid view with objectDataSource it gives an id to the grid view like `DataSourceID = "ObjectDataSource1"`

and in web form cs file i am using DataSource, so when running it complains that i am using both DataSource and DataSourceID .
BTW i am doing these all for implementing grid view sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `DataSourceID = "ObjectDataSource1"` from the .aspx page.

Depending on what's returned, you might need to get a table out of the dataset:

```
GridView1.DataSource = OrdersData.GetOrders(txtSearchInOrders.Text).Tables[0];
```